# Xamarin - Java.Lang.Thread vs System.Threading.Thread - which one to use?

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.android

On a Xamarin project that I have been working on recently I can see that developers had used **Java.Lang.Thread** as well as **System.Threading.Thread** (for very similar actions - for example loading data in the background).

I am just wondering what is the reasoning behind using **Java.Lang.Thread** in a Xamarin project where Thread class is inheriting from **IDisposable** so it would only make sense to make sure it's disposed properly as well (meaning it's an extra code).

What does perform better in the Xamarin ecosystem?
Are they basically interchangeable?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. If you downvote, you should be able to explain it.

Comment: I am not an expert of Xamarin, but I think they should be the same since the C# code is eventually translated to Java.

Comment: @Sweeper That is an incorrect statement, the C# (or F#, ...) code is not translated to Java, it is IL-based and runs in the Mono Runtime that is wrapped into an Android NDK-based app. The Java ART VM is made available via a bridge so you can access the Android Java SDK.

Comment: @SushiHangover Sorry! I don't know much about Xamarin!

Comment: @Sweeper NP, just do not want something thinking that some type of trans-compiling is going on. With the `Xamarin.Android` stack there truly are two VMs available, the .Net/Mono/CIL and Java/Dalvik/ART... and your .Net-based code can call into the Java-side of Android and use those features as transparently as possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just want to mention that the `System.Threading.Thread` derives from the [`CriticalFinalizerObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.constrainedexecution.criticalfinalizerobject.aspx), which is a safe one implementation of the standard [Disposable pattern from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx):

> Ensures that all finalization code in derived classes is marked as critical.

rather than `Java.Lang.Thread` only implements the `IDisposable` interface.

Another difference between these classes is that they are slightly different in definition. Let's take a look for documentation:

**Java.Lang.Thread Class**:

> A `Thread` is a concurrent unit of execution. It has its own call stack for methods being invoked, their arguments and local variables. Each application has at least one thread running when it is started, the main thread, in the main [`ThreadGroup`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.Lang.ThreadGroup/). The runtime keeps its own threads in the system thread group.

*The linked article says that the usage of the thread groups is considered as outdated.*

**System.Threading.Thread Class**

> A process can create one or more threads to execute a portion of the program code associated with the process. Use a [`ThreadStart`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Threading.ThreadStart/) delegate or the [`ParameterizedThreadStart`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart/) delegate to specify the program code executed by a thread. The [`ParameterizedThreadStart`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart/) delegate allows you to pass data to the thread procedure.

Also it derives from [**`_Thread`**](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Runtime.InteropServices._Thread/):

> Exposes the Thread class to unmanaged code.

*This interface is for access to managed classes from **unmanaged code** and should not be called from managed code.*

So, as I can see, the java-one thread is a logical structure inside the JVM rather than c#-one is something unmanaged-consuming one. I suggest you to measure up the resources for one implementation and another, and decide which class to use accordingly.

If many of your code is based on the .NET side, I suggest to use the CLR implementation. In other case I think that you should use the JVM implementation.